# What does "in hearing" mean in this sentence?

Tags: verbs, nouns, questions, sentence-meaning

> In hearing so many people relate the fascinating experiences with which this volume deals, I have come to feel almost as though I have lived through them myself.

What does "In hearing" mean?

Comment: *In the process of hearing. Since I hear. As I heard.* After hearing stories, I started to feel them inside.

Comment: 'After hearing' or even just 'Hearing' could have been used instead. Or even 'As a consequence of hearing': the dependent clause is causative (or part-causative).

Comment: What @EdwinAshworth said. Personally I find preposition ***in*** clumsy/unnatural in the cited context. There are lots of alternatives, but I'd go for ***Through** hearing [something so often...]*

Comment: Thank you all very much for your answers! @Yosef Baskin, Edwin Ashworth, FumbleFingers